# How to extract the $parameters array from the __callStatic() method for further conversion to a string using the __ToString () method?

Tags: php, class, static, public, self

```
class Concatenator
{
    private static $string = [];

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {   
        self::$string = $parameters;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return str_replace(' ', '+', strtolower(self::$string));
    }
}

$concatenated = Concatenator::prepareString('I am concatenated');

echo $concatenated;
```

I can't figure out how to pass the value from the magic `__callStatic()` method to the magic `__toString()`.

Please tell me what is wrong with the code? Why doesn't `__toString()` see `self::$string`?

Answer (score 0):

`$string` is an `array`, not a `String`:

```
private static $string = [];
```

so you cannot pass it to `strtolower` by itself. You might want to change its initialization to `String`:

```
private static $string = "";
```

and to pass `$parameters` as a `String` value instead of an array. Or, if it is correct to have an `array`, then you will need to use its proper index.